# Using JQuery how do you create a control the name of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using append in the following way:

```
$('#city').append('<div class="c">' + value['name'] + '. ' + value['city'] + ', ' + 
                        value['state'] +' ' +  value['zip'] + ' ' + '</div>');
```

Which results in something like this:

```
<div class="c">
Antone Stark. Doyletown, Rhode Island 43467 
</div>
```

**How do you use value['state'] to name the class?**

```
<div class="MyCustomClass">
```

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. Ask again?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set a CSS class to be not "c" but "state_RI" for Rhode Island?

Comment: sorry I forgot to classify the code as code and it was hidden.

Comment: You already know how to do string concatenation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the states were two letter codes, you could do this:

```
$('#city').append('<div class="'+value['state']+'">' + value['name'] + '. ' + value['city'] + ', ' + 
                    value['state'] +' ' +  value['zip'] + ' ' + '</div>');
```

However, classes are space-separated meaning they are treated as separate when split up by spaces. So if you add something there with a space (like "Rhode Island"), it will treat them as separate classes (e.g., "Rhode" and "Island") so you may wish to replace spaces with an underscore or the like.

```
$('#city').append('<div class="'+value['state'].replace(/ /g, '_')+'">' + value['name'] + '. ' + value['city'] + ', ' + 
                    value['state'] +' ' +  value['zip'] + ' ' + '</div>');
```

So in the case of Rhode Island, that will produce:

```
<div class="Rhode_Island">
```

which you can then reference in CSS:

```
.Rhode_Island {color:blue}
```

or jQuery:

```
$('.Rhode_Island').... (do something)
```

etc.

However, if you are not repeating these, it might be more appropriate to generate it as an id rather than a class (i.e., to produce `<div id="Rhode_Island">` instead of `<div class="Rhode_Island">`).

Answer (score 1):

`$('#city').append('<div class="' + value['state'].replace(/ /g, '_') + '">'` ...

Comment: Edited to integrate brettz9's suggestion of replacing spaces with underscores.